# Meteor - Error storing uploaded file to TempStore

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

I am having issue on uploading the files to my `FS Collection`.

When first launched with MUP I had no issues. Now I am getting an error in mup logs saying:

```
Error: Error storing uploaded file to TempStore: EACCES, open '/opt/kpinsonstairs-deploy/cfs/files/_tempstore/images-8r5w8T5cuknAE3SS4-0.chunk'
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (packages/cfs_collection/packages/cfs_collection.js:161:1)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (packages/cfs_tempstore/packages/cfs_tempstore.js:343:1)
    at WriteStream.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at WriteStream.<anonymous> (fs.js:1669:12)
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
error: Script restart attempt #1
```

I have read how this could be a permission issue with my `FS Collection` `images`.

However, I have open permissions for uploading to this collection's path.

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [
    new FS.Store.FileSystem("images", {path: Meteor.absolutePath + '/private/uploads'})
  ],
  filter: {
    maxSize: 2097152, // 2MB
    allow: {
      contentTypes: ['image/*']
    }
  },
  onInvalid: function (message) {
    if (Meteor.isClient) {
      alert(message);
    } else {
      console.log('error: ' + message);
    }
  }
});

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Images.allow({
    insert: function () {
      return true;
    },
    remove: function () {
      return true;
    },
    download: function () {
      return true;
    },
    update: function () {
      return true;
    }
  });

  Meteor.publish('images', function() {
    return Images.find({});
  });
}
```

I have not been able to find an answer on how to solve this issue.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So 'EACCES' is indicative of a file system level permission issue.

"However, I have open permissions for uploading to this collection's path" -- i'm not sure if this means that you have already checked filesystem permissions -- but that is what you need to do:   Check the permissions on the directory `/opt/kpinsonstairs-deploy/cfs/files/` and make sure that the user that you are using for running your software has read/write/execute permission to that directory.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to fix it like you said by using `sudo chmod -R 775 /opt/kpinsonstairs-deploy/cfs/files`. I am just confused as to why initially I did not have to do this, then all of the sudden it stopped working and required this permission error. When I redeploy mup for updates. Will I have to continue to do this?

Comment: You don't say anything about if you manage the running of the software yourself -- but in all likelyhood, you have either started to run your software under a new user, or some OS update have tightened the security of of your system removing permissions from directories under `/opt`, or (this is the paranoid answer) somebody have hacked into your system and in an attempt to cover their tracks they have deleted some directories and recreated them again, but with wrong user/permissions....